# Inner difference of if('0') between C and PHP?

Tags: php, c

Will someone explain the inner difference of if('0') between C and PHP?
In C, if('0') gets false, while in PHP gets true.

Comment: In C, `if('0')...` would evaluate to `true` because, assuming ASCII, `'0' == 0x30`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the *"C"* language, which dates from the 1970's, is a good bit more *literal* than PHP!  **:-)**

First of all, the "C" language really has no concept at all of "a `string` data type." *"None of that had been **invented** yet."*

Furthermore, the compiler *"presumed that you actually knew what you were doing."* (That is to say, "that you would not feed it 'nonsense.'")  Being a very *literal* language, it presumed that you must be thinking the same way.

Fast-forward at least one human generation, and we come to "PHP."  CPU's are now *vastly* more-powerful than a PDP-7 ever was, and memory is an order-of-magnitude bigger, and by now we're trying to "bend the *language's* interpretation of things, to better match "ordinary *human"* meanings, instead of the other way around.

Thus, the **PHP** language sees `"0"` as "`false`-y." Instead of restricting its point-of-view to "a particular storage representation," as **C** is *designed(!)* to do, PHP sees `"0"` as being *"zero"* ... even though, strictly-speaking, it is "a string" ... and thus sees it as: "`false`-y."

Yeah ... "potential interpretations of the meaning of source-code" **have** **indeed** "changed in forty-plus(!) years ..."

Comment: Nitpicking: At least in C `'0'` (which the OP is asking about) isn't a "string", but just a character, a `char`.

Comment: Exactly so.  But if you are more familiar with other languages, like PHP, it does not *look* like one. Therefore, "C" will superficially appear to *accept* the same source-code construct, yet it will regard what it sees in a totally different way. It will see it as a `char`, and it just might *compile it* without warning.

Comment: I need to correct myself. `'0'` is a character **literal**, which in C is represented as an `int`. And the Standard leaves it open, which value it will evaluate to. Depending on the supported character-set it *could* very well evaluate to `0`, which would make `if ('0')` become `false`. It doesn't for ASCII, however :-)

Comment: Correct ... and, to a person who cut their teeth on "modern" languages, altogether unexpected.